# Python in ArcGIS to utilize python-docx - IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, arcpy, errno, python-docx

I am still relatively new to python and I am attempting to translate the output from a Script Tool I designed in Python to produce a Microsoft Word Doc.
I keep receiving:

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '5_26_2016.docx'

Can anyone explain what I have done or how I could possibly fix this.  The code is listed below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Sm8.png)

```
new_Survey_Date = Survey_Date.replace("/","_") # split method returns a list   
outTitleDoc = str(new_Survey_Date)
docNum = 1
print "OUTPUT DOC:" , outTitleDoc
for theFile in ARCPY.ListFiles ("*.docx"):
    if os.path.exists(outTitleDoc):
        newOutTitleDoc = outTitleDoc
        while os.path.exists(newOutTitleDoc):
            newOutTitleDoc = outTitleDoc + "new" + str(docNum)
            docNum = docNum + 1
        outTitleDoc = newOutTitleDoc
outTitleDoc = outTitleDoc + '.docx'
document.save(outTitleDoc)
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if your script is simply `open('5_26_2016.docx', 'w')`?

Comment: Yes.  Specifically:

Comment: File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\zipfile.py", line 756, in __init__
    self.fp = open(file, modeDict[mode])
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '5_27_2016.docx'

Failed to execute (ExecutiveReport).

Comment: I don't think you follow me. The code you've posted in your question: delete it *all* and replace it with only the code `open('5_26_2016.docx', 'w')`. Run the code. What happens? I'm trying to isolate what your problem comes down to. I don't think it has anything to do with ArcGIS or docx.

Comment: Okay I give it a shot thanks again for the help.  My end goal for this code is for it to create a new docx file and populate it with the result from the script tool.  It must be able to read through and recoginze if there is already a file with that name with the parent folder and if so then it must append "new1" , "new2" , etc to the new docx file.

Comment: Alex you were a great help, but I ended up tearing down my code to discover that I am an idiot and was not providing the entire path name for the parent folder.  It was that it wouldn't open.  It could find the folder it needed to in order to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Always double check your pathnames to the parent folder. It was that it wouldn't open. It could not find the folder it needed to in order to open it.